# server and client side socket programming?

Tags: javascript, webclient

A server wants to send a message to client app(java script).
if the client got the message, it will activate sth.(realtime)
Should I use socket.io?
What kind of library or method can be used?

Answer (score 2):

**Socket Programming**

sockets provide the communication mechanism between two computers using TCP. A client program creates a socket on its end of the communication and attempts to connect that socket to a server.

When the connection is made, the server creates a socket object on its end of the communication. The client and the server can now communicate by writing to and reading from the socket.

The java.net.Socket class represents a socket, and the java.net.ServerSocket class provides a mechanism for the server program to listen for clients and establish connections with them.

The following steps occur when establishing a TCP connection between two computers using sockets −

The server instantiates a ServerSocket object, denoting which port number communication is to occur on.

The server invokes the accept() method of the ServerSocket class. This method waits until a client connects to the server on the given port.

After the server is waiting, a client instantiates a Socket object, specifying the server name and the port number to connect to.

The constructor of the Socket class attempts to connect the client to the specified server and the port number. If communication is established, the client now has a Socket object capable of communicating with the server.

On the server side, the accept() method returns a reference to a new socket on the server that is connected to the client's socket.

After the connections are established, communication can occur using I/O streams. Each socket has both an OutputStream and an InputStream. The client's OutputStream is connected to the server's InputStream, and the client's InputStream is connected to the server's OutputStream.

**There are two types of soket:**

**Server Socket** - is created to bind() to a port and listen() for a connect() from a client. So a server just waits for a conversation and doesn't start one.

**Client Socket** - is created to connect() to a listen() server. The client initiates the connection.

**server App**

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServerApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        ServerSocket Server_Socket;
        Server_Socket = new ServerSocket(5555);

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        clientSocket = Server_Socket.accept();

        DataInputStream input;
        input = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(input.readUTF());

        DataOutputStream output;
        output = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String str = "", str2 = "";
        while (!str.equals("stop")) 
        {
            str = input.readUTF();
            System.out.println("client says: " + str);
            str2 = br.readLine();
            output.writeUTF(str2);
            output.flush();
        }
        input.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        Server_Socket.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

**Client App**

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Socket Client_Socket;
        Client_Socket = new Socket("localhost", 5555);

        DataInputStream input;
        input = new DataInputStream(Client_Socket.getInputStream());

        DataOutputStream output;
        output = new DataOutputStream(Client_Socket.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String str = "", str2 = "";
        while (!str.equals("stop")) {
            str = br.readLine();
            output.writeUTF(str);
            output.flush();
            str2 = input.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Server says: " + str2);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        Client_Socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what technology you like. WebSockets are really good for solving real time problems. Socket.IO is able to fire events on the client and server side and react to these events on the other side.

Socket.IO runs great on a Node JS server. (http://nodejs.org/)

In this example (https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat) you see a chat realized via socket.io. Instead of displaying the results to the users screen you could simply fire events on the client side with a switch.